# mysql denormalization with triggers, specific advice

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb, myisam, denormalization

I'm considering adding some denormalized information in my database by adding **one** denormalized table fed by **many (~8)** normalized tables, specifically for improving select query times of a core use case on my site.

The problems with the current method of querying are:

1. **Slow query times,** there are  between 8 and 12 joins (some of the left joins)  to access the information for this Use Case this can take ~ 3000ms for some queries.
2. **Table Locking / Blocking**, When information is updated during busy times of the day or week, (because I'm using MyIsam tables) queries are locked / blocked and this can cause further issues (connections running out, worse performance)

I'm using Hibernate (3.5.2), Mysql 5.0 (all MyIsam tables) and Java 1.6

I'd like some specific suggestions (preferrably based on concrete experience) about exactly what would be the best way to update the the denormalized table.

The following come to my mind

1. Create a denormalized table with the **InnoDb** type  so that I get **row** level locking rather than table locking
2. Create triggers on the properly normalized tables that update the denormalized table,

I'm looking for:

1. Gotchas - things that I may not be thinking about that will affect my desired result.
2. Specific MySql settings that may improve performance, reduce locking / blocking on the denormalized table.
3. Best approaches to writing the Triggers for this scenario.
4. ?

Let me know if there is any other information needed to help answer this question.

Cheers.

Comment: Are the data for the denormalization stricly numbers? Are the denormalization operations stricly algebraic?

Comment: How much data are you talking about? 10 rows? 10M rows? You might be better served with more / better / covering indexes. Is the query static? You might be able to pre-cache it too. What does the 'explainer' say about your query?

Comment: the operations are all algebraic (i think), no like string comparisons or fulltext string searches

Comment: ehtrbunny, in the linked tables there are around 680k, 250k, 2.3k, 5k, 16k, 680k, 250k, .5k, 140k, 253k, 250k rows in the main select query.  the explain (explainer) all lines show that an index is being used.

Comment: Will adding triggers to existing MyISAM tables to update the denormalized table change *anything* about how those MyISAM tables are locked during updates?

Answer (score 2):

I've now implemented this, so I thought I'd share what I did, I asked a mate who's a dba (Greg) for a few tips and his answers basically drove my implementation:

Anyway like "Catcall" implied using TRIGGERS (in my case at least) probably wasn't the best solution.  Greg suggested creating two denormalized tables with the same schema, then creating a VIEW that would alternate between the two denormalised tables one being "active" and the other being "deactive" the active table would be the one that was being actively queried by my web application and the deactive table could be updated with the denormalised information.

My application would run queries against the VIEW whose name would stay the same.

That's the crux of it.

Some implementation details (mysql 5.0.n):

I used stored procedures to update the information and then switch the View from denorm_table_a to denorm_table_b.

Needed to update the permissions for my database user
GRANT CREATE, CREATE VIEW, EXECUTE, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, DROP, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, ALTER, SELECT, INDEX on dbname.* TO 'dbuser'@'%';

For creating a copy of a table the: CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ....; command is really useful (it also copies the index definitions as well)

Creating the VIEW was simple
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW denorm_table AS SELECT * FROM denorm_table_a;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW denorm_table AS SELECT * FROM denorm_table_b;

I created a special "Denormalised Query" Object in my middle tier which then mapped (through hibernate) to the denormalised table (or View in fact) and allowed easy and flexible querying throught Hibernate Criteria mechanism.

Anyway hope that helps someone if anyone needs any more details let me know,

Cheers
Simon

Comment: May I ask why you decided against triggers? And do I understand correctly, that you a) always rebuild the complete table before b) redirecting the view and c) keeping the queried table read-only?

Comment: @sfussenegger I decided against trigger as they would fire frequently and lock the denorm table (I'm using myisam tables) basically firing too many write operations on the denorm table.  Regards your other points a) yes, b) yes c) yes

Answer (score 1):

Here is I solution that I used to denormalize a mysql one-to-many relation using a stored procedure and triggers:

https://github.com/martintaleski/mysql-denormalization

It explains a simple blog article to article image relation, you will need to change the fields the fields and queries to apply it to your scenario.

Comment: @AdamEasterling I added a new link to github.